# Availability of a project id for google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I used to be able to check the availability of a project id for google app engine. I can no longer find a way to do that. Is that not possible any more?

Will the approach of browsing for a potential project id like this `projectid.appspot.com`, then if it returns a 404 error tell me that `projectid` is available?

**update**

Perhaps I should say why I want to know whether a project is available.
[The following wording](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate) suggests that once a project id is taken, it cannot be undone. `The project ID is the globally unique identifier for your project. You cannot change the project ID after the project is created.` It does not tell whether or not just entering an id commit me to using that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for availability by trying to create a project with that name.  You'll get a message immediately if the name is not available.

If you later decide that you don't want to use it, you can delete the project.

Is there a reason why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Once, when I was requesting a name, the system would not give me the name and just appended several digits to the requested name and forced that name on me. It is unacceptable to me to have a project ID with appended digits. Also, I do not desire to waste project names on unused projects, because projects are limited. Thanks, for your reply. Are you pretty sure that I will get such a message (that the id is unavailable)?

Comment: Well, I don't recall the precise message, but if the ID is available you will get it.  If not, Google might append digits or say that it is not available.  I have a GAE ID that matches the name of my company.

Comment: You were right about there being an opportunity to abort if the pure name was unavailable. My only scare was during deployment when GAE said `target url:      [https://my-id.uk.r.appspot.com]`. But it looks like the extra `uk.r` is not required for user access. I'll have to see when that extra is required.